# How to manipulate SET datatype in MySQL with fast binary operations?

Tags: mysql, set, bit-manipulation

I want to efficiently store and efficiently manipulate bit flags for a record in MySQL. The **SET** datatype satisfies the first wish because up to 64 flags are stored as a single number. But what about the second? I have seen only awkward solutions like

```
UPDATE table_name SET set_col = (set_col |  4) WHERE condition;
UPDATE table_name SET set_col = (set_col & ~4) WHERE condition;
```

to respectively include and exclude a member into the value. I.e. I have to use numeric constants, which renders the code unmaintainable. Then I could have used **INT** datatype as well. If `set_col` definition gets changed (adding, removing or reordering the possible members), the code with hard-coded constants becomes a mess. I could try to enforce some discipline on coders to use only named variables in application language instead of numeric constants which would make maintenance easier, but not totally error-proof. Is there a solution where *MySQL would resolve the symbolic names of set members to their correct numeric values*? E.g. this does not work:

```
UPDATE person SET tag=tag | 'MGR'
```

To stem useless answers, I know about database normalization and a separate m-to-n relationship table, that is not the topic here. If you need a more concrete example, here you are:

```
CREATE TABLE `coder` (
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `languages` SET('Perl','PHP','Java','Scala') NOT NULL
)
```

Changes to the set definition are unlikely but possible, maybe every other year, like splitting "Perl" into "Perl5" and "Perl6".

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html

> Posted by John Kozura on April 12, 2011
>
> Note that MySQL, at least
>   5.1+, seems to deal just fine with extra commas, so setting/deleting individual bits by name can be done very simply without creating a
>   "proper" list. So even something like SET flags=',,,foo,,bar,,' works
>   fine, if you don't care about a truncated data warning.
>
> add bits:

```
UPDATE tbl SET flags=CONCAT_WS(',', flags, 'flagtoadd');
```

> delete bits:

```
UPDATE tbl SET flags=REPLACE(flags, 'flagtoremove', '')
```

> ..or if you have a bit that's name is a subname of another bit like
>   "foo" and "foot", slightly more complicated:

```
UPDATE tbl SET flags=REPLACE(CONCAT(',', flags, ','), ',foo,', ',')
```

> If the warnings do cause issues from you, then the solutions posted
>   above work:
>
> add:

```
UPDATE tbl SET flags=TRIM(',' FROM CONCAT(flags, ',', 'flagtoadd'))
```

> delete:

```
UPDATE tbl SET flags=TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', flags, ','), ',flagtoremove,', ','))
```

Comment: This is still not good enough, integer math `column|4096` and `column& ~128` is much faster.